# Drawing on zoomed imageview in scrollview in ios?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, drawing

Hi friends i am creating ipad app where i am using UIImageView In UIScrollView. So when i zoomed image and try to draw some thing, it is not drawing on that point where i touch. How much i zoomed it it got difference in drawing and creates image on top left corner instead  of centre . 
Guys suggest me. 
here is my code

```
if (isFreeHand==YES) {
    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    self.frame = CGRectIntegral(self.frame);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, self.opaque, 0.0);

    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];

    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x-mWidht, lastPoint.y-mHeight);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x-mWidht, currentPoint.y-mHeight);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
     self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self.tempDrawImage setAlpha:opacity];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
}
```

Comment: I guess you should use `contentOffset` and `zoomScale` to calculate the correct point.

Comment: @rokjarc how to use it??

Comment: I'll try to write a hypotetical answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

When image is scaled it appears bigger than it is. It's origin might not be at (0,0). So you have to recalculate the *real* position of the touch.

For clarification:

```
zoom scale ... zs
image offset ... (oX,oY)
touch coordinates ... (tX,tY)
translated touch ... (rtX,rtY)
```

If zoomed image's origin is still in (0,0) then you would 
translate touch like this:

```
rtX = tX/zs; 
rtY = tY/zs;
```

if images origin would be off (0,0) by an offset (oX,oY) and
zoomscale would be 1.0 you would translate touch like this:

```
rtX = tX+oX;
rtY = tY+oY;
```

Putting it all together (offset and zoom), translation would go 
like this:

```
rtX = oX + tX/zs; //with oX zoomscale is allready taken into account
rtY = oY + tY/zs; //with oY zoomscale is allready taken into account
```

Note that these calculations might not be completely correct since
i didn't test them. But they should get you started.

There might even be a more elegant (built-in) solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

On the fourth line replace `self` with the name of your UIImageView:

```
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView: self.tempDrawImage];
```

The locationInView actually makes the coordinates of a touch relative to a certain UIView, which is just what you need.